# Activity-Paw Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, pawserver

I'm trying write an app using PAW server for which a demo code is also available.

I'm want to start an activity but I can't do so as I can't find what the problem is.

This is the click part of code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Intent ConnectionIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ConnectionActivity.class);
                startActivity(ConnectionIntent);
                } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error" , e.getMessage());    
            }

        }
```

I've added in Andriod manifest file and here is the code:

```
   <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ConnectionActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONNECTIONACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I can't figure out where I've made a mistake.

Here is the log:

> 03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Final.Year.Project.ConnectionActivity
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at Final.Year.Project.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:26)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5226)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
>   03-09 23:43:21.306: E/AndroidRuntime(16685):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the full package name in

```
android:name=".ConnectionActivity" >
```

For example

```
android:name="xx.yy.zz.ConnectionActivity" >
```